# Play movie from NSFileWrapper in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdata, nsfilewrapper

How do you play a movie given a [`NSFileWrapper`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFileWrapper_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

I expected to find a `initWithData:` constructor in `MPMoviePlayerController` (as in [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithData%3aerror%3a)), but only [`initWithContentURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/initWithContentURL%3a) is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the filename for an `NSFileWrapper` node by sending it the `- filename` messsage. From there, you can turn that into an `NSURL` using `– initFileURLWithPath:`, which should do the trick because you can then call `initWithContentURL:`.